# Self Contained / Cooled Rack Enclosure

Tags: rack

I'm looking at having to place a few servers in a location that does not provide a 'friendly' environment (moderate dust, no HVAC, ok physical security).  Can anyone recommend a 'self contained' rack enclosure that provides cooling, air filtration, and a lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want a cabinet with integrated air conditioning.  There are several companies that manufacture cabinets that either have air conditioning built into the cabinet itself, and others that have the A/C unit mounted outside of the cabinet (such as on the back).

[Rackmount Solutions](http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/Air_Conditioned_Server_Rack.asp) carries some of these.  As others have mentioned, other vendors such as [APC](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=107) and [Sun](http://www.sun.com/products/sunmd/s20/) also manufacture modular systems that include A/C, but they tend to be more expensive.

Answer (score 5):

The racks at http://www.kellsystems.com offer exhaust fans and have optional air filter modules. Each rack has a speced heat load that it can handle. The nice things about these racks is they look like furniture in an office environment.

Comment: These are neat solutions where the air temp is suited for equipment.

Answer (score 2):

HP sell a [water-cooled, sealed rack](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/en/WF04a/3447589-3447589-3446285-3446371-3461917.html) that's also pretty secure - lets you run up to 35Kw/rack too, very spendy though, VERY.

Plus it needs cold water feed and exit plumbing too. Other than this, rather extreme, solution I can't think of there being anything that contains active-cooling inside the rack, where would the heat/condensed water go?

Answer (score 0):

I like [Sun's black box concept](http://www.sun.com/products/sunmd/s20/). It might be way over your requiremnents but it still fits them all.

Comment: That is totally cool!

Answer (score 0):

[APC - Now Liebert](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=107) has some cooling systems designed for rack level coooling.  One thing you didn't mention was how much noise you can tolerate.

They typically will assign someone to help you design the appropriate system from they selection of racks, UPSs and other devices.

Answer (score 0):

[APC's InfraStruXure range](http://www.apc.com/products/infrastruxure/index.cfm) have been around for a while and meet your feature list.

Answer (score -1):

My company does these racks, www.intelcab.co.za 
let me know if you are interested in getting one.

Comment: It is fine to memtion your company's products, but I'd prefer if you also pointed at alternatives (perhaps closer to home for OP). Suggest terms to search for, perhaps clarify the specifications.